# Why does it need two end statement on the last 3 and 5 lines?

Tags: ruby

According to [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm), I only need one `end` statement for the `if`, `elsif`, and `else` loop:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  nums = num.to_s
  final_string = ''
  i = 0 

  while i < nums.length
    if i == 0
      final_string += nums[i]
      if nums[i].to_i % 2 == 1
        final_string += '-'
      end
    elsif i == nums.length
      final_string += nums[i]
    else
      if i % 2 == 1
      final_string += '-'
      final_string += nums[i]
    end
  end
  i += 1 
end
puts final_string
end
```

Why do there need to be two `end` statement between `i += 1`?

Comment: Your `if i % 2 == 1` block isn't properly indented.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is important:

```
def dasherize_number(num)
  nums = num.to_s
  final_string = ''
  i = 0 

  while i < nums.length
    if i == 0
      final_string += nums[i]
      if nums[i].to_i % 2 == 1
        final_string += '-'
      end
    elsif i == nums.length
      final_string += nums[i]
    else
      if i % 2 == 1
        final_string += '-'
        final_string += nums[i]
      end
    end
    i += 1 
  end
  puts final_string
end
```